# Building Visual Studio projects to a common directory rather than bin?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

Is it possible to build projects to a common directory, instead of the per project `bin` folder?

The purpose would be to make it easier to source control all my binaries. How can I do it and, what are the pitfalls of this approach?

You have the option to build projects to another directory (a common directory?) rather than the `bin/debug` and `bin/release`.

Comment: binaries in source control? Why?

Comment: @Mitch so you have a canonical location for them.  My question is why not source control them in `bin`; you should be source controlling the whole project?

Comment: because not all members of the team have access to all projects but most projects require the references from other projects. If that makes sense.

Comment: use a post-build step to copy to a shared read-only location

Comment: @Mitch It can make sense to add binaries to source control in larger projects were other projects are getting the binaries (and pdbs) but don't need the source at all. Of course you could also move them to a share, but why not rather use the "share" which the source control is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean DLL files/assemblies, then you build to `bin/release` as usual, then copy the DLL files you require to a common directory and then reference those, so when you rebuild the original solution, you don't have to worry about which version you are using or recompile other related projects as the version hasn't changed in the common dir.

Comment: cool, so your only allowing them to ref the dll's in the common dir, not the solution bin/release directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean building your projects and putting the DLL files in a shared folder, yes, we currently do this, but we use this using [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI), so we can know when a change in a project caused another project to break.

You may also experience problems when you use a version-specific DLL file as referenced in your other projects.

You can also, rather than having a bat file copy over the DLL files, use Visual-Studio's built in post-build command. It's the same as a batch file, with the exception that no special setup is required in [CruiseControl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) to copy over the files. If a developer makes a change to the post build command it and check it in it will automatically be executed by CruiseControl.

Also, if you'd like your developers to shared the binaries I'd put them in [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) to make sure everyone share the same DLL files rather than their own local built copy of the DLL file (which might be different than the actual build server as some compile directives might/might not be defined).

Answer (score 1):

It happens that people build to another folder than bin (e.g. the bin folder in the solution directory rather than the project directory). I doubt you would have any problems doing this. But since you're going to check it in, you must remember to not have it read-only (so you can build over them). Source control programs often lock the files.

You could also consider having a bat script that copies the files to another location after a successful build.

Answer (score 1):

***For C++ projects:***
Right click on the project -> Properties -> Linker -> Output File 
set your directory there.

***For C# Projects:***
Right click on the project -> Properties -> Builld -> Output Path

Answer (score 0):

I would not put your binary output into source control. Only put the source files, project files and solution files.

Answer (score 0):

We use post-build scripts to copy to the intended location.  This works, but is very fiddly (as the scripts are awkward to write & awkward to debug).